# Boostrap nested row only works above columns not below

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want a row with 7 columns taking up 100% of the width then nested in that row on the next line I want 1 column also taking up 100% of the width.

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27598/ The message column is in the wrong place completely.

https://jsfiddle.net/w37vs3wr/1/ the message column is the right size but the wrong place. I want to make it exactly like this but below the other columns not above them.

```
        <div class="row bg-warning">
            <div class="col-xs-1">Result</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Start</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Duration</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">Test Case</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Total Data Items Generated</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Type</div>
            <div class="col-xs-1">Username</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">Message</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to make a row that you divide in 7 and a second row with a column taking the all space.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">Result</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">Start</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">Duration</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Test Case</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">Total Data Items Generated</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">Type</div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">Username</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">Message</div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27601/

*Note:* the background color is just to ensure that the *Message* take the full width

Comment: You can also wrap the entire snippet into a row